# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition - Can't view Git commits after Updating Project

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Am using the following version of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition:

```
IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2.3 Ultimate Edition
Builde #IU-202.7660.26, built on October 6, 2020

Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.34 x86_65
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

on macOS Catalina 10.15.7 with the following version of git installed:

```
git --version
git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
```

Whenever, I click on the diagonal blue button to Update Project from my specified Git repository:

[image: Update Project using Git]

Whereas, it downloads and specifies the number of files that were updated, when I click on the view commits link:

[image: No commits displayed]

It doesn't show which files were updated!

Is there a place in IntelliJ's preferences that might have been unset?

Comment: Why did my post get a -1 vote? This is after all a very legitimate question that needed to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have log window hidden at the left side.
Could you please locate your mouse on a left border of "Update" toolwindow and see whether "Resize" coursor appears and if so, please drag in to the right. Then you should be able to see a log of updated files.